# Notepad++ wont show or open /opt/ files and directories

Tags: permissions, gedit, opt

Ubuntu Version : 18.04 LTS

I have given all persmission on /opt directories. I am able to view edit and save files in the /opt/ directory from gedit. But Notepad++ doesnt show any folders or files in /opt/ directory as seen in the below images.

I am new to ubuntu and picking it recently. So if its a basic issue please help out.

I installed notepad++ from the software updater.

Gedit screenshot:

[image: Gedit screenshot]

Notepad++ screenshot:

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]

Update:
Below are my permissions for /opt

```
    shahul@shahul-Inspiron-3576:~$ ls -l /opt
    total 20
    drwxrwxrwx 3 shahul shahul 4096 Jul 18 19:37 eclipse
    drwxrwxrwx 3 shahul shahul 4096 Jul 15 22:24 google
    drwxrwxrwx 3 shahul shahul 4096 Jul 19 14:33 notes
    drwxrwxrwx 6 shahul shahul 4096 Jul 19 17:31 softwares
    drwxrwxrwx 3 shahul shahul 4096 Jul 18 14:51 springboot
```

Comment: Difference with gedit: you installed notepad++ as windows software using WINE.  Make sure the wine user can access /opt/*.  Do a  `ls -l /opt` and add the results into the question.

Comment: i added the results all permissions are there

Answer (score 0):

That's because either **Wine** or **Notapad++** itself does not have permission to access that folder.

Modifying access to a root folder is not a wise move though. Try running it with ***sudo***.

Comment: sudeo notepad-plus-plus doesnt work . App doesnt launch. I am the only one going to be using the computer and hence i gave full access to /opt directory alone